# Getting headers of a remote excel file using requests and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have a function that, using pandas and requests, pulls a .CSV file into a pandas dataframe and return the headers.  Works great, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

def getcsvheader(file):
    print('Getting file...')
    res = requests.get(file)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.text))
    return(df.columns.tolist())
```

I want to do the same for an excel file, but I'm not sure of the fourth line above.  If I simply change read_csv to read_excel I get errors like:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
```

Obviously because the excel file does not read as text, so (io.StringIO(res.text)) needs to be replaced with something, but with what?

Or is there another way to accomplish this? (Any combination of libraries will do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas can use URLs and excel natively.  If you just need the header row from a URL, this should get you there:

```
import pandas

URL="https://example.com/test.xlsx"

def get_excel_headers_from_url(URL)
    return pandas.read_excel(URL).columns.tolist()
```